# Music does not play after clicking back key and returning to activity in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to play Audio using videoView using MediaController. The Audio is playing well, when I click back key the controls returns to previous state. But when I select activity again from launch screen, activity appears but music doesnot play. Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue?
The code is as follows:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video);

        videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
      videoView.setVideoPath("http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/video/famous.3gp");
        final MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        videoView.setMediaController(mc);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/tutorials/audio.mp3"));


        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this)
        {
            public void hide()
            {
                System.out.println("HIDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEHELLLOO");
                mc.show();
            }
        });




}


public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {        
        moveTaskToBack(true); 
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to play the music only when the activity is in the foreground, you want to start and stop the music in `onResume` and `onPause`, not onCreate.

Take a look at the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).  OnCreate is only invoked once when the activity is created.  If the activity goes into the background and then reappears, it may not be called.

Answer (score 0):

```
# use this code...the song plays even if the user presses his back button #

public void playAudio(){
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mp.setDataSource("/sdcard/fileaudio.mp3");
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //playAudio();   
        }   
    });   

}
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent
        .setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);

    finish();
}
```